# VB.NET to download latest file name with timestamp in its name from FTP server

Tags: vb.net, ftp, timestamp, filenames, ftpwebrequest

I want to pull a file from my FTP server into my local drive. However the most difficult part of do this is that the file name is a timestamp that changes on a daily basis. The program should download the file regardless of how it has changed with the date; year, month, hour, minutes, and seconds. The format of the name are always the same. File name example is below in bold. Please advise!

For example,
username - meUser
password - mepswrd
and the URL to the FTP
`/afea/euser/aefe/aole/efa/`
and the path I want the file to save after download it.
`C:\Users\alae\Desktop\loaef`
and the file is in FORMAT
**`20160223.171234.BA_DESRP_20160121.txt`**

The only part to the file that doesn't change is `BA_DESRP`, all the other part can change as it is a timestamp.

This is my code to start with:

```
Const lf As String = "C:\Users\alae\Desktop\loaef"
Const rf As String = "/afea/euser/aefe/aole/efa/"
Const ht As String = "host"
Const un As String = "username"
Const pw As String = "password"

Dim URI As String = ht & rf
Dim ftp As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = _
    CType(FtpWebRequest.Create(URI), FtpWebRequest)

ftp.Credentials = New _
    System.Net.NetworkCredential(un, pw)
```

Comment: You need to first get a listing of files in the directory, and then fetch the one you want to download if there are multiple files. Lookup WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

Comment: Ok but all those files (multiple of them) they all have similar format (timestamp) that changes. Could you provide an example - I will look at your suggestion too ?

Comment: Think about it.  A File name is a `String` so what you're asking is basically how to determine whether a `String` contains another `String`.  I'm quietly confident that you will find LOADS of information on the web on how to do that, if you even need more than that.

Comment: Is there always only a single `BA_DESRP` file in the FTP folder?

Comment: so let me make sure i understand the problem. the directory that you download from is going to have multiple files with the same file naming convention, but whenever you go there to grab the file, you always want to grab the latest one correct? so as long as there is not like thousands of files in this directory, the .Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails method should allow you to do what you want here. once you return the list of files, you can either examine the timestamp, or work that out your self from the file name to figure out which one is the latest. i will add code that returns the file list

Comment: actually check this out http://jstawski.com/post/2007/02/23/downloading-multiple-files-from-an-ftp-using-wildcards

Comment: -Gungor, yes you are correct, I want the latest file and the file naming convention is the same and there could be hundreds or maybe thousands of files.

Comment: Martin - no there are tons of other file, but they are all unique since there is a time stamp to the seconds. I just want to pull the most recent file down from there.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way with the `FtpWebRequest` (or any other functionality readily available in the .NET framework). You have to:

- List the remote directory using the `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory`
- Filter the returned list to those containing the `BA_DESRP`
- Select the latest out of those
- And download it

```
Dim url As String = "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/"
Dim credentials As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
Const localPath = "C:\local\path"

Dim listRequest As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
listRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
listRequest.Credentials = credentials

Dim latest As String = Nothing

Using listResponse As FtpWebResponse = listRequest.GetResponse(),
      listStream As Stream = listResponse.GetResponseStream(),
      listReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(listStream)
    While Not listReader.EndOfStream
        Dim filename As String = listReader.ReadLine()

        If filename.Contains("BA_DESRP") Then
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} ...", filename)

            If (latest Is Nothing) OrElse (latest < filename) Then
                latest = filename
            End If
        End If
    End While
End Using

If Not latest Is Nothing Then
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading {0} ...", latest)
    Dim webClient As New WebClient()
    webClient.Credentials = credentials
    webClient.DownloadFile(url + latest, Path.Combine(localPath, latest))
End If
```

---

Or use another FTP library with more powerful functionality.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

```
Const localPath = "C:\local\path\"
Const remotePath = "/remote/path"

Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With sessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Ftp
    .HostName = "ftp.example"
    .UserName = "username"
    .Password = "password"
End With

Using session As New Session
    session.Open(sessionOptions)

    Dim latest As RemoteFileInfo =
        session.ListDirectory(remotePath).Files.
            Where(Function(file) file.Name.Contains("BA_DESRP")).
            OrderByDescending(Function(file) file.Name).
            FirstOrDefault()

    If Not latest Is Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading {0} ...", latest)
        session.GetFiles(latest.FullName, localPath).Check()
    End If
End Using
```

If you can use the actual file timestamp (not the timestamp in its name), it would be even more straightforward. See [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file#alternatives).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the list of files in the directory. Since your file name already includes the timestamp, you just need to parse it out from the file name, and then ultimately store each timestamp in a variable where you can then compare the next file's time stamp to. if next file is greater than the value you in your variable, assign that value. finally when you are done, your var should reflect the file name you need and at that stage you can call the download method to get the file.

```
 Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & "servername" & "/" & "directory" & "/*")
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
    request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

    Using reader As New StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        Do Until reader.EndOfStream
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine())
        Loop
    End Using
```

since you say thousands for files, this route may not be the best option for you. if you are not restricted to .NET, you may want to explore alternative options, such as using a ftp client where you may be able to search by the actual time stamp on files...

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and code example. It looks great. What kind of alternative are you speaking of, what kind of FTP client, is FTP client a software, could you give me an example ?

Comment: yes, but one more suggestion. do you know what day you are searching for everytime? So when you run this, is it always looking for file created today, or yesterday? if you know that, you can certainly limit your search criteria with the code i posted, see that wildcard used, that can help eliminate searching the entire directory as such; \WebRequest.Create("ftp://" & "servername" & "/" & "directory" & "/20160223*")